# make Html.Editorfor field readonly in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I am using this, an editor template (located in the Shared\EditorTemplates folder in my solution)

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
  <%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), ViewData )%>
```

and this in my view

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
```

how to make this field readonly in the view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.ModifiedDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

---

UPDATE:

OK, now that you sent me the sample project here are the issues:

1. You have a spelling mistake in the `~/Views/Shared/EditorTempletes` folder. It should be `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`.
2. You editor template must be called `DateTime.ascx` and not a `DateTime.aspx`. And because of this the header must look like this (use `<%@ Control ...` instead of `<%@ Page ...`):

   ```
   <%@ Control 
       Language="C#" 
       Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" 
   %>
   <%= Html.TextBox(
       "", 
       (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty), 
       ViewData
   ) %>
   ```

Comment: @TJK, I have just tested this and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe you can send me a sample project illustrating the issue so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: how do i send a sample project?

Comment: @TJK, you can mail me at `darin[DOT]dimitrov[AT]gmail[DOT]com`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor()
```

Answer (score 2):

Decorate the property with the [HiddenInput] Attribute from the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I use to show read-only information this way:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CadastradoEm, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CadastradoEm)
```

You need to include a *hidden input* in addition to the display text, cause `DisplayFor()` doesn't generate a control that posts back 
;)